# After the update on react-scripts 3.0.1 TypeScript error. How to find the cause?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

After the update on react-scripts 3.0.1, all tests are run in the application, but when you try to start the application `(for example, yarn build)`, the following error occurs:

> Failed to compile
>   TypeScript error in `[internal](undefined,undefined)`:
>   Debug Failure. Diagnostic emitted without context TSINTERNAL_ERROR

Comment: Still having this issue...